# Is there any way to tell a standard launch mode activity to close itself?

Tags: android

I'm maintaining an Android app that's a remote control for a manufacturing process.  The main Activity screen has some buttons which launch other Activity screens to control factory equipment, but the Main Activity also has a thread to communicate with a PC over the network, and the PC itself might launch or want to stop some of those subordinate Activities (which it does via the thread started in the main activity).

Here's the problem:  the subordinate Activities are all Standard Launch Mode but in the course of the manufacturing process they have to be opened and closed many times and sometimes these closes will be initiated from outside the subordinate Activity, say, from the thread that talks to the PC.  How do I have the main activity of my task close standard launch mode activities that it created so I don't end up spawning lots of duplicate activities?

I can't change the subordinate activities to Singletask or SingleInstance because they don't support onActivityResult().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your subordinate activities and have the parent send a [broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) when it receives the PC command. You can have diferent broadcasts for each subordinate activity.

In the receiver you just have to do whatever you want (call finish() for example).

Comment: This sounds promising ... I'll try that and post back here to indicate my results.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [android:noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) is what you are looking for:

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack
>   and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away
>   from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be
>   finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". A value of
>   "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It
>   will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will
>   not be able to return to it.

The correspondent java falt to [set into your intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) is [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).

```
Intent i = new Intent(...)
i.setFlag( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY );
```

hope this helps

Comment: I don't necessarily want to kill it just because it's no longer visible, because the subordinate activities themselves might spawn other things, like graphics viewers.  I only want to kill it when the thread talking to the PC receives a command from the PC saying to kill it.